# Print Data from Excel in Word with VBA Makro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to print Data from my Excelsheet to a table that already exists in an already existing word File.

My Data in excel is a simple question like: "What is the weather like?"

Now I want to print this question in to a table in word.
The Word File and the table is already existing.

First I'm opening the word file from my excel makro.

```
Dim AppWD As Object

Set AppWD = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Word als Objekt starten

AppWD.Visible = True
AppWD.documents.Open "file location"

doc.Unprotect
```

This works perfectly fine, but then I'm first of all trying to remove a Row in that table as a test, i do that like this:

```
AppWD.Tables.Item(1).Rows(2).Delete
```

But here's the problem, this doesnt work.
I always get the **Run-time error '424':
Object required**

I think the problem is that my makro doesn't know that it has to write in to word and not into my excelsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not creating and using your objects correctly. is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Dim AppWD As Object, doc As Object

Set AppWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")

AppWD.Visible = True

Set doc = AppWD.documents.Open("file location")

doc.Unprotect

doc.Tables.Item(1).Rows(2).Delete
```